# Google Form API?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-forms-api

I would like to (programmatically) convert a text file with questions to a Google form. I want to specify the questions and the questiontypes and their options. Example: the questiontype scale should go from 1 to 7 and should have the label 'not important' for 1 and 'very important' for 7.
I was looking into the [Google Spreadsheet API](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/) but did not see a solution.
(The Google form API at http://code.lancepollard.com/introducing-the-google-form-api is not an answer to this question)

Answer (score 15):

Google released API for this: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/

> This service allows scripts to create, access, and modify Google Forms.

Comment: Note that this is not a REST API, but rather a feature of Apps Script.

Comment: Is there an official CDN from Google to include the script(s)?

Comment: Is it only available for G Suite customers??

Comment: @SlickSlime - Possibly (even likely), because it is included in G-Suite services. I never *used* this API, I just found it when I was doing a research for our in-house project similar to OP's question. That project was never started, sadly, so I do not have first-hand experience (but I do have constitutionally-protected right to have opinion, even if I never used it :-)  We use G-Suite so for us such requirement would not be a problem.

Answer (score 7):

Until [Google satisfies this feature request](http://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=993) (star the feature on Google's site if you want to vote for it), you could try a non-API approach.

[iMacros](http://wiki.imacros.net/Introducing_iMacros) allows you to record, modify and play back macros that control your web browser. My experiments with Google Drive showed that the basic version (without DirectScreen technology) doesn't record macros properly. I tried it with both the plugin for IE (basic and advanced click mode) and Chrome (the latter has limited iMacro support). FYI, I *was* able to get iMacros IE plug-in to create questions on mentimeter.com, but the macro recorder gets some input fields wrong (which requires hacking of the macro, double-checking the ATTR= of the TAG commands with the 'Inspect element' feature of Chrome, for example).

Assuming that you can get the TAG commands to produce clicks in the right places in Google Drive, the approach is that you basically write (ideally record) a macro, going through the steps you need to create the form as you would using a browser. Then the macro can be edited (you can use variables in iMacros, get the question/questiontype data from a CSV or user-input dialogs, etc.). Looping in iMacros is crude, however. There's no EOF for a CSV (you basically have to know how many lines are in the file and hard-code the loop in your macro).

There's a way to integrate iMacro calls with VB, etc., but I'm not sure if it's possible with the free versions. There's another angle where you generate code (Javascript) from a macro, and then modify it from there.

Of course, all of these things are more fragile than an API approach long-term. Google could change its presentation layer and it will break your macros.

Comment: A forms API is now supported. (docs are [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/?hl=es-ES).)

Comment: Is it possible to run the Form API in Java or C#?

Comment: @JeffreyLin doesn't look like it yet... https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I had checked the page. However, I do not find "Google Forms API" or "Google Apps Script API" in the listings. Therefore, I would like to know whether it is possible to run Forms API with these libraries or not.

Comment: @Greenhand Create your script on their google engine, then kick it off using their REST API. So you can't write it in Java or C#, but you could cause execution of a script in those languages.

Answer (score 6):

Seems like [Apps Script](https://script.google.com/) now has a [REST API and SDK's](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/quickstart/python) for it. Through Apps Script you can generate Google Forms. This API was really hard to find by trying to google for it and I haven't yet tested it myself, but I am going to build something with it today (hopefully). So far everything looks good.

EDIT: Seems like the REST API I am using works very well for fully automated usage.

Answer (score 3):

In March(2022) google released [REST API](https://developers.google.com/forms/api/reference/rest/v1/forms) for google form. API allows basic crud operation & also added support for [registering watches](https://developers.google.com/forms/api/reference/rest/v1/forms.watches) on the form to notify whenever either form is updated or a new response is received.

Answer (score 1):

As of now (March 2016),  Google Forms APIs allow us to create forms and store them in Google Drive. However, Forms APIs do not allow one programmatically modify the form (such as modify content, add or delete questions, pre-filled data, etc). In other words, the form is static. In order to serve custom, external APIs are needed.

Comment: How about dynamically updating form response data based on previously entered data by the same user? This is similar to allow user to modify their response after form submission. The difference is to pre-create response in the form based on user email address.

Comment: The Google Form API doesn't include methods to make the form dynamic but the question isn't about that and the answer isn't not clear, I think.