# color code google form answers automatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-forms

I create student tests in Google Forms. I create an answer key by submitting a form response with all of the right answers and then use an arrayformula to compare student submissions to my submission to get the number of correct responses. I typically create conditional format rule for each column that changes the background of any correct answers in that column green. I would like to automate this by a similar means as the way the array formula works by simply comparing the student submission for that column to the correct submission for that column (found in row 2) and then changing the background green. I would love to use a script but I don't know how to start to write one (but am will give it a try if someone would like to give some guidance). Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you got so far? Do you have any code to show? Have you gone through the docs yet?

Comment: I don't have any code. I'm familiar with JavaScript (beginner) and think that iterating through the cells in row 2 (the answer key row) and comparing them to cells in the new submission would be the way to do it, but I don't know how to begin. I'm not looking for anyone to do the work for me, but need to be pointed in the right direction to get started. This would be my first script other than "hello world!"

Comment: Looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8604992/google-form-api this answer, it might not be possible programmatically at the moment.

Comment: Nevermind! I stand corrected. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/?hl=es-ES Should get you started -- it appears to be well documented.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to begin researching the Google Forms API here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/?hl=es-ES

> This service allows scripts to create, access, and modify Google Forms.

It looks like it has some basic javascript examples that should get you started with simple form manipulation, and once you're comfortable there, implement Javascript [loops](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) and [comparisons](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp).

In the event that you need a more complex matching platform for text-based answers, [regular expressions](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) or more commonly [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) will help you accomplish that.

Comment: Thank you for pointing the way! I will get started on this and see where it takes me.