# Is there a Google Forms API that can be used by 3rd party products?

Tags: google-api, google-forms

I am looking to create a personalized form using the user data in my product database.

I have already checked this link - [Google Form API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8604992/google-form-api). It talks about automating forms via Google app-scripts. That is not what I am looking for.

I want to programmatically create a Google Form instance from the user data in my product database and then send the form to the user.

Comment: You'd need to create your own api using a published [tag:google-apps-script] web-app. You can then programmatically access  your web-app api using your favorite language.

Answer (score 0):

The only way provided by Google to programmatically create a Google Form is by using the Google Apps Script Forms service (Class FormApp)