# how to get iframe innerHTML to represent what is actually visible on the page?

Tags: javascript, select, iframe

So here's a crazy thing that happened to me.

I want to embed a Google form in a website. I need to automatically populate and hide one of the form fields.

Here is some html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head> </head>
  <body>
    <iframe
      src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdisob821_bYS5Ya_r460Bn0RHYSB5xqIW6Yz-z4WPwEVjxMQ/viewform?embedded=true"
      width="640"
      height="734"
      frameborder="0"
      marginheight="0"
      marginwidth="0"
      >Loading...</iframe
    >
  </body>
</html>
```

Nice and simple. Now if I run that in my browser (currently Chrome) The form shows up just fine. I see it with my own eyes. I am not intoxicated in any way.

Now in my developer tools console I do this:

```
formFrame = document.querySelector("body > iframe");
formFrame.innerHTML;  // the value is "Loading..."
```

So js believes we are still displaying placeholder text? Odd.
I dont really care to work directly with innerHTML. What I want is more like this:

```
inputContainers = document.querySelectorAll("div.freebirdFormviewerViewNumberedItemContainer");
```

The length should be 2. It is 0

If I look at the html element tree in my dev tools everything seems to be there as it should be.

I use the "inspect element" function of my dev tools just to make sure the selectors I am using are correct.

I then execute `formFrame.innerHTML` again. I get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: formFrame is not defined`. Gosh

I then execute this again:

```
inputContainers = document.querySelectorAll("div.freebirdFormviewerViewNumberedItemContainer")
```

and it returns two elements.

## Getting to the point

I assume my messing around with the "inspect element" functionality of my developer tools fired off an event that caused the dom to be populated properly. How do I make that happen from inside my code?

I'm very worried that I might be hitting against some security feature and I wont be able to use google forms in my application.

Any help or insight will be appreciated!

Comment: You need the content of said iframe but it's Google so you'll probably need to use Google's API specific to the service. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8604992/2813224)

Comment: @zer00ne thanks for your input but I really dont believe that is the case. Maybe I didn't make my question clear enough. Basically this is what happens. (1.) I open the page. It looks great. I can see the google form clear as day (2) I press F12 and try to use js to explore the internals of the iFrame and fail. As far as JS is concerned the content of the page is "Loading...". In other words JS thinks what I am looking at is placeholder content. But I can see the form (3) I click the  "inspect element tool" then click on one of the form elements that are already visible and totally available

Comment: @zer00ne (3 ...) Inspecting the element behaves like normal , I'm looking at an `<input ...`  (4). I attempt step 2 again and this time js doesn't think there is a placeholder. It returns what I'm actual looking at. So in step (4) ` formFrame.innerHTML` represents reality. And in step (2) it simply does not

Comment: iframes are accessible from console but that's about the extent of it. There are security measures (ex. Same Origin Policy) that prevent any real manipulation of iframe's content (content meaning the actual real page located at the `src`). `.innerHTML` property will return the targeted element's content ***between the start tag and end tag*** as a literal string (aka htmlString). In other words do not rely on what the console shows concerning iframes, it cannot be accessed programmatically.

Comment: @zer00ne Thank you for taking the time to explain. If you post that as an answer I'll accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this is not possible. It's a security feature